# Gun that points towards player doesn't work

Tags: unity-game-engine

In my 2D Platformer, there is a flying enemy that has a gun. The gun sits at 0° or 180° on the Z axis depending on which way the enemy is facing. The gun is free to move 30° either way. When the enemy is facing right, it works perfectly but when the enemy is facing left it resets to 150° when it gets to 180°. Can any one help? Here is my code:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class EnemyGun : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;
    private bool isRight;

    private void Update ()
    {
        if (player.position.x - transform.position.x < 0)
        {
            isRight = false;
        }
        else
        {
            isRight = true;
        }

        Vector3 dir = player.position - transform.position;
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

        if (angle > 30 && isRight == true)
        {
            angle = 30;
        }

        if (angle < -30 && isRight == true)
        {
            angle = -30;
        }

        if (angle > 210  && isRight == false)
        {
            angle = 210;
        }

        if (angle < 150 && isRight == false)
        {
            angle = 150;
        }

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please Don't use any tag in the title of question

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider a different design to this. If you make your gun a child of the enemy unit object then you will only have to deal with 1 range of angles.

You also might want to look at http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html this for easier implementation.

To answer your question directly:

Mathf.Atan2 will return angles from [-PI, PI] so your code will give some problems just because of this.

I advise to make your gun a child of the enemy and then code the angles as follows:

```
// using your angles in the question
angle = Mathf.Abs(angle); // only need positive angles.
angle = Mathf.Clamp(angle, 30, 150);
```